# In rails, why is my finder method only returning one result when I want it to return all of them?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, find, ruby-on-rails-5, finder

I'm using Rails 5.0.3.  How do I find all matching records using a finder?  I have

```
my_obj = self.find_by_name_and_day_and_user_id(name, day, user_id)
```

but it returns only a single result.  When I run turn on the SQL, it is adding a

```
 LIMIT 1
```

clause.  How do I write a finder method that will return all results and not just one?

Comment: `find_by_*` always return a single result. Use `where` instead (which is less verbose and closer to the SQL syntax): `where(name: name, day: day, user_id: user_id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `where`, like so

```
self.where(name: name, day: day, user_id: user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_by` method always return first matching record. So you should use `where` clause which will return all matching records.

```
my_obj = self.where(name: name, day: day, user_id: user_id)
```